# Create a new session with same group-name, preserving current window in new session

Tags: tmux

(For context: I have the following slightly unusual use case for tmux because I am using the Overmind process manager, which uses its own tmux server connection internally.)

When I create a new session with the same group-name as a previous session so that the group of windows is shared between these two sessions, I would like to automatically start the new session with its "current window" open to the same "current window" as the first session.

So for example, if I have a session called `overmind` with the following windows, and window 2 is the current window:

`1 2* 3`

When I call `:new-session -t overmind` inside this session, I'd like the new session with the same group of 3 windows to start, with window "2" set to the current window:

`1 2* 3`

When I run `:new-session -t overmind` now, however, it starts the new session like so:

`1* 2 3`

How do I accomplish setting window 2 to be "current window" automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with `tmux 3.3a`:

```
:run 'sess=`tmux new -d -P -t "#{session_name}"` && tmux switch-cli -t "${sess}#{window_index}" '
```

You can bind to a key in tmux.conf for convenience like this:

```
bind z run 'sess=`tmux new -d -P -t "#{session_name}"` && tmux switch-cli -t "${sess}#{window_index}" '
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching and trying things for hours. I have an adapted version below that suits our specific need.

Answer (score 0):

I adopted your code to work as a set-hook so that a new terminal tab automatically creates a new session within the session-group:

In `overmind.tmux.conf`:

```
# Create a new session within the same overmind session-group, and switch to the same window_name.
# This allows us to open a different "current window" in each new Terminal tab (tmux default
# is to create a shared session with shared "current window" in each Terminal tab).
set-hook -g client-attached "run 'sess=\`tmux new -d -P -t \"#{session_name}\"\` && tmux switch-cli -t \"\${sess}#{window_index}\"'"
```

Comment: the quoting can be a bit simpler if your session is always using simple name: ``set-hook -g client-attached "run 'sess=`tmux new -d -P -t #{session_name}` && tmux switch-cli -t \${sess}#{window_index}'"``